# Pass Object from one Aspx to another from Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

Correct me if I am doing wrong.

I have a Login page which uses a Webservice to process login. In my Login page I use Jquery with JSon to consume the webservice.

After the login is processed I recieve an object and I want to redirect the recieved object to home page.

Let me know how.

Thanks
Samuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST` redirect the received JSON to server, and deserialize the JSON to your typed object. You can consider keeping the object in your SESSION and access it when required.

**UPDATE**

put a hidden field in your aspx/ascx page

Once you receive your JSON Data from your service. Just put your response to the hidden field. (USE JQUERY)

```
$("input[id$=jsonResponse]").val(responseFromService);
```

On your `Page_Load` method on your `home.aspx`

Use `JavaScriptSerializer` to deserialize your JSON data

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

LoginData loginDataObject = serializer.Deserialize<LoginData>(jsonResponse.Value);
```

Now you can consider putting your `loginDataObject` to `SESSION` and access through out your application scope

```
// to store in session
Request.Session["loginData"] = loginDataObject;
// to retrieve from session
LoginData loginDataObject = (LoginData) Request.Session["loginData"];
```

Comment: Munim, any link or sample mock code is appreciated as I am a Newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the object in a [cookie](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html) and change the url with location.href or something similar?

Comment: Hi Neil,Is there any other way apart from cookies? I feel like all customers may not enable cookies and times it become hard to trace.

Comment: Aren't cookies used to persist a login across requests? There's @Munim ASP.NET session option - but I'm pretty sure session requires cookies too (unless the id is in the querystring which looks dreadful). I can't think of another way, sorry.